# ¿Cómo generar cronjobs con PHP?

Tags: php, crontab, cron

Dentro de un proyecto necesito que el usuario tenga la opción que desde su portal administrativo pueda generar cron jobs (varios) para lanzar ciertas acciones cada determinado tiempo.

Intenté con este código pero no sé si sea el correcto. Lo que hace es que almaceno en un TXT las instrucciones a ejecutar:

```
echo exec("crontab -r");
$output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
$cron_file = "./crontab.txt";
$add_cron = "* * * * * cd /home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/proyect; /usr/local/bin/php -f script_cron.php";
file_put_contents($cron_file, $output.$add_cron.PHP_EOL);
echo exec("crontab $cron_file");
```

No sé si exista alguna otra forma más óptima de hacerlo o que me recomiendan para este tipo de situaciones en las que el usuario tenga que generar sus propias tareas programadas.

Comment: me parece peligrosísimo dejar al usuario generar sus propios cronjobs y editar el crontab programáticamente

Comment: Que opción pudiera optar para que el usuario pueda generar tareas programadas??

Comment: agrega solo un cronjob y PHP te encargas de hacer todo lo correspondiente

Comment: yo tengo un administrador de cron job; simplemente programe las posibilidades existente y en cuanto a ejecucion de tiempo. y lo demas lo guarde en base de datos y en los php

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación @FranciscoNúñez me pudieras proporcionar un ejemplo del trabajo que realizaste de favor.

Comment: esta no es el mio pero es una libreria que te puede ayudar saludos: https://www.phpclasses.org/package/8266-PHP-Schedule-jobs-stored-in-files-and-MySQL.html

Comment: Muchas gracias @FranciscoNúñez

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un crontab que puedes llamar miPrimerCronTab.sh con las siguientes líneas:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
php  /ruta/de/tu/archivo/tareaUsuarioJob.php t=1
php  /ruta/de/tu/archivo/tareaUsuarioJob.php t=2
```

Si deseas que se ejecuten secuencialmente, usa wait entre cada llamada a tu archivo, nota la variable t es por si tu script necesita una variable tipo get en este caso.

Con esto vas a un Administrador de tareas de cron o por línea de comandos, por ejemplo si deseas que se ejecute cada 5 minutos:

```
 */5    *   *   *   *  /ruta/de/tu/archivo/CronTab1.sh
```